# Laravel - Delete record from database if not exists in given array

Tags: php, database, laravel, github, cron

I am fetching all my GitHub repositories using [Campbells GitHub package](https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-GitHub) for Laravel. I made a command and a cronjob which runs every minute and it works perfectly fine. The only problem is that when a repository gets deleted from GitHub it stays in my database instead of also getting deleted.

I came across a method called `whereNotIn()` which checks if the data does not meet the specified input and you can do actions to it accordingly. But I can't seem to make it work.

Say for instance this bottom table is a list of GitHub repos and my repos in my database

```
GitHub Repos.   |    Website repos

Repo 1          |    Repo 1
Repo 2          |    Repo 2
Repo 3          |    Repo 3
Repo 4          |    Repo 4
                |    Repo 5
```

You see that the list of GitHub repos is one short of the website repos, which means a repo got deleted on the GitHub side so in that case Repo 5 also needs to get deleted to stay up-to-date with the changes.

**Handle method within the command**

```
public function handle() {
        $repos = GitHub::connection('main')->me()->repositories();

        foreach($repos as $repo) {
            $name = str_replace(".", "-", $repo["name"]);

            Project::whereNotIn('name', $name)->delete();

            DB::table('projects')
                ->updateOrInsert(
                    ['name' => $name],
                    [
                        'name' => $name,
                        'html_url' => $repo["html_url"],
                        'description' => $repo["description"],
                        'stargazers_count' => $repo["stargazers_count"],
                        'language' => $repo["language"],
                    ]
                );
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as following:

```
public function handle() {
    $repos = GitHub::connection('main')->me()->repositories();
    $existingReposNames = [];

    foreach($repos as $repo) {
        $name = str_replace(".", "-", $repo["name"]);
        $existingReposNames[] = $name;
        

        DB::table('projects')
            ->updateOrInsert(
                ['name' => $name],
                [
                    'name' => $name,
                    'html_url' => $repo["html_url"],
                    'description' => $repo["description"],
                    'stargazers_count' => $repo["stargazers_count"],
                    'language' => $repo["language"],
                ]
            );
    }

    Project::whereNotIn('name', $existingReposNames)->delete();
}
```